# checking for null value using dapper.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am using dapper to read values into an object I created where I us a basic stored procedure.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT LOWER(UT.UserID) FROM UserTable UT WHERE UT.UserID = @UserId)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    UT.UserID,
    UT.Name, 
    UT.Surname, 
    UT.TrackingString
    FROM UserTable UT
    WHERE UT.UserID = @UserId
END
```

and this is the code in my view model.

```
 IDbConnection connection;
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Liberty"].ToString()))
        {
            var result = connection.QueryMultiple("GetUserData", new { UserId = userId.ToLower() }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            user = result.Read<UserData>().First();

        }
```

How can I check in the result if columns were selected..
As it is at the moment I get an InvalidOperation Exception if there is no user data(if the user does not exist).

Comment: Check if result object is null before you try to read from the object, ex: `if(!result.Equals(null)) { user = ...;}`

Comment: have tried that already. Does not work

Comment: The SP design is so strange, normally it should return the same structure for any data even none matched.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks, it is a but silly making the check in the SP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct Linq method.  You're using one that treats no results as an invalid result, whereas your query may return no values if no such user exists.

Switch to a method that doesn't throw on no elements in the return enumerable, then check for null and handle it gracefully.

```
    // snip
    user = result.Read<UserData>().FirstOrDefault();
}
if(user == null)
{
    // no such user exists, go do something about it
```

Comment: I know this post is old but just to help people if they run across the same issue like I did today, this answer is no longer valid in the current version of Dapper.
 Instead use:
 `cart = results.ReadFirstOrDefault<ContractModels.Cart>();
                    if (cart == null)
                        return null;`

Comment: @JosephWhite I can't find any information about that on the innertubes.  Do you have a reference link with details?  I'll use it to update the answer to include this info.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I never saw anything on the internet either that would indicate the above answer would not work. As a matter of fact, as long as a  value is returned or if you do a .ToList().FirstOrDefault() it still works. The problem comes if you don't convert it to a list first but the select statement returns nothing. After much searching, I found the ReadFirstOrDefault() method for dapper and that solved my issue

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to want to update the answer. I don't contribute to SO as much as I get from it. I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using QueryMultiple? Use Query<> instead. Then just do result.Count() before result.first(). Or do FirstOrDefault()

Might I also suggest that you create a class to receive the data?

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID {get; set;}
....
}
```

Then use connection.Query("....", new...)

Much nicer to the eyes.